# How do two types of carriers in intrinsic semiconductors contribute to its plasma frequency?

Tags: optics, solid-state-physics

In the simplest expression, the plasma frequency of a plasma is inversely proportional to the effective mass of the mobile carriers.
$$
\omega_p \propto \frac{1}{\sqrt{m}}
$$
In an intrinsic semiconductor, there is an equal number of conduction electrons and holes as the mobile carriers. Generally they have different effective masses, so which one should I choose to compute the plasma frequency?

*Additionally*, is it possible to think about this in a phenomenological manner? I would like to know how the two different types of carrier having different properties inside the same solid affect the interaction of that solid with any incoming light. For the time being I would like to know how they affect the transparency of the semiconductor.

**My thoughts so far**:

The plasma frequency acts as some kind of "low-cut filter". Light of frequency lower than it do not pass through the solid. Thus, the "effective" (I do n0t know whether it is appropriate to use the term here) plasma frequency would be the higher one corresponding to the carrier with less effective mass.

Comment: There is a way to combine the effective masses of the two contributions. Now, since you are talking about a semiconductor, the conductivity should be low enough that you should not see the plasma low cut filter behaviour.